# How to run a CA as another user?

Tags: installation, installshield, custom-action

My installation is always executed in a Computer where I know the user/password of a user with administrator privileges.

The installation needs Administrative privileges to execute so I created an EXE that executes the installation using this known user.

My problem know is that the installation launches an EXE from a Custom Action once the installation is finished. This EXE is executed also with Administrative Privileges as the installation itself has this privileges.

Is there a way to launch an EXE from a Custom Action using a different user that the one is executing the installation???

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention custom action, can I assume you are using a Windows Installer based project type?   If so, MSI already provides a mechanism in which your CA can run without impersonation in an elevated System context. ( Deferred Execution in System Context )

[Installation Phases and In-Script Execution Options for Custom Actions in Windows Installer](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/isnews/200108/index.htm)